# change url #firstPage with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, fullpage.js

I use the fullpage plugin (from https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ ) in wordpress but I want to delete #firstPage in the url but use the buttons so I can't use the noAnchor (https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/noAnchor.html). can I rewrite the URL with htaccess? something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/#firstPage$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

http://www.example.com/#firstPage/1

Comment: No. That's not possible. You can rewrite fregment as # is not sent to the server. # is manipulated client - side only so use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want anchors in the URL, don't use anchors in the fullPage.js initialisation.

Then bind the [`moveTo`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide) method to your menu elements.